# Mapbox iOS SDK 2 markers cluster

Tags: ios, cluster-computing, mapbox, markers

The deprecated MapBox iOS SDK version 1 has some classes and examples for helping create markers cluster. In its new iOS SDK version 2 however this functionality is somehow gone or is not explicitly exposed. The closest class, MGLPointAnnotation, doesn't seem to have anything to indicate if an Annotation is clustered or not. Anybody else has similar issue or has found a solution/workaround?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no support for clustering yet in 2.x: https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-native/issues/320

Comment: what about sdk version 3?